# scheduling script from sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a script daily_status_22.sql as

```
set feedback off;
set pages 0;
set term off;
column dt new_value _dt;
column mn new_value _mn;
select 'C:\Users\rjen01\Desktop\'||to_char(sysdate,'MON')||'\' from dual;
host mkdir mn;
select to_char(sysdate,'ddMONyyyy_hh24mi')||'.csv' dt from dual;
spool &_mn &_dt;
select sysdate from dual;
spool off;
```

and i run 
@C:\Users\rjen01\daily_status_22.sql
 as script by pressing F5.

How can i use scheduler to schedule to run command 
@C:\Users\rjen01\daily_status_22.sql 
as a script and not as a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things.

What you can't do is schedule SQL Developer (GUI) directly to start, connect, and run a .SQL file as a script.

However, we do have a CLI for SQL Developer, it's called SQLcl. Newer versions (4.1+) will have this binary (SQL.exe on windows) in the BIN directory.

You can call it from your OS .bat/.sh scripts just like you would with SQL*Plus. It has the ability to run anything SQL Developer can and also anything SQL*Plus can.

You can ALSO just run your script via SQL*Plus. You'll need to get an Oracle Client to run SQL*Plus. And you'll want to test the script in SQL*Plus first to make sure it works the way you expect since you developed it first in SQL Developer.